# Lost php as a file type sublime 3

Tags: php, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I tried installing a package to sublime 3 in order to beautify my php however, I tried deleting the package manually in .config/sublime3/packages or equivalent, then realised that you can configure removing a package with package manager. So I went and did that anyway. Unfortunately now, I have no php language at all in the bottom right corner where you can select the language.

Is there a way to reinstall the php language package or fix this issue without having to reinstall?

Thanks! usr/error.. :(

Comment: fixed it.. will post when it lets me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I solved this,

I went to my `.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User` folder, opened the `Preferences.sublime-settings` and deleted the array that had for some reason put php in the ignored modules.

Comment: You never know when you'll help somebody. Seems like I installed a shitty outdated plugin that did exactly what you described here.